# Strip and reorder text from one file to another

Tags: text

Hi all — apologies in advance for a perhaps completely ignorant question. I am not a programmer, but have a problem that I think will be easy to solve, and will very much appreciate any pointers — either toward specific techniques or toward resources that I can use to find the answer myself.

I need to strip data from one text file (an edit decision list file [EDL]) and reorder and output it in a new text or CSV file.

My input file looks like:

```
027  BL       V     C        00:00:00:00 00:00:01:09 00:26:14:20 00:26:16:05

028  AX       V     C        00:59:56:13 00:59:59:06 00:26:16:05 00:26:18:22
* FROM CLIP NAME: Many people had already come to this country

029  BL       V     C        00:00:00:00 00:00:00:21 00:26:18:22 00:26:19:19

030  AX       V     C        00:59:56:06 01:00:00:18 00:26:19:19 00:26:24:07
* FROM CLIP NAME: and I saw that they arrived and bought a car and made a home.
```

I want to select only lines with "AX       V" in positions 6-15 and the following lines, extracting characters 54-64 and 66-76 from the first line in each pair, and characters 19-end from the second, to output:

```
00:26:16:05 , 00:26:18:22 , Many people had already come to this country
00:26:19:19 , 00:26:24:07 , and I saw that they arrived and bought a car and made a home.
```

Any thoughts about how this could be accomplished? I'm afraid I don't even know what language to do this in. Any help at all will be greatly appreciated, either a way to do this directly or a pointer toward online resources to learn how to do it myself.

So, hoping that I'm not needlessly clogging up the board and that others will find this helpful... a great many thanks in advance!

Joe

Comment: Its kind of an opinion question. I'd say Python is easy enough to install and write the script for a non-programmer. Its `splice` built-in feature would help a lot.

Comment: The language you know is the language you'll use. Personally I'd use Ruby, but just about anything would do if it has even rudimentary string and file handling. You don't even need regular expressions, since you already know exactly the character positions of everything you're after.

Comment: Many thanks Mephy and matt. I'll take a look at those and see what I can figure out.